# terraform destroy failed to delete postgresql database

Tags: postgresql, terraform

My **Terraform** scripts happily creates a **Postgresql** instance with three databases, and a **Kubernetes** cluster with three deployments. It works nicely. When I run the destroy it almost works, but it fails when deleting one of the database instances with this

```
Error: Error reading Database: googleapi: Error 400: Invalid request: Failed to delete database "xyz". Detail: pq: database "xyz" is being accessed by other users. (Please use psql client to delete database that is not owned by "cloudsqlsuperuser")
., invalid
```

**Terraform** has already reported that the k8 pod that uses that database has been destroyed (actually all the pods have been destroyed) and nothing else accesses that database. A second try at running the destroy succeeds in removing the database just fine, suggesting that the suggestion in brackets is not needed here.

I suspect the pod is managing to hang on longer than **Terraform** expects and it reports the destroy of the pods a little bit soon. I certainly have some flags in there to prevent the pods shutting down too fast. But I have not yet found a way to put a delay or retry into **Terraform's** processing of the destroy for the database.

Is there a way to do that?

This is the **Terraform** that creates my databases and, of course, destroys them too.

```
resource "random_id" "db_name_suffix" {
  byte_length = 4
}

data "http" "myip" {
  url = "http://ipv4.icanhazip.com"
}

data "null_data_source" "my_ip_allowed" {
  inputs = {
    name  = "tf"
    value = chomp(data.http.myip.body)
  }
}

resource "google_sql_database_instance" "master" {
  name             = "${var.environment}-sql-${random_id.db_name_suffix.hex}"
  database_version = "POSTGRES_11"
  region           = var.region

  settings {
    tier             = "db-custom-1-3840"
    disk_autoresize  = "true"
    disk_size        = "10"
    disk_type        = "PD_SSD"
    replication_type = "SYNCHRONOUS"
    pricing_plan     = "PER_USE"
    ip_configuration {
      ipv4_enabled    = "true"
      private_network = "projects/${var.project}/global/networks/default"
      require_ssl     = "false"
      authorized_networks {
        name = "creatorIP"
        value = chomp(data.http.myip.body)
      }
    }
  }

  # Generate the DDL scripts that will be used when the databases are created.
  # and change the postgres password  
  provisioner "local-exec" {
    command = "chmod +x ddlsetup.sh && ./ddlsetup.sh ${google_sql_database_instance.master.name} ${var.dbpassword}"
  }
}

resource "google_sql_database" "xyz" {
  name      = "xyz"
  instance  = google_sql_database_instance.master.name
  charset   = "UTF8"
  collation = "en_US.UTF8"
  provisioner "local-exec" {
    command = "psql -h ${google_sql_database_instance.master.public_ip_address} -p 5432 -U postgres -d xyz -f \"/tmp/xyz-postgres.sql\""
    environment = {
      PGPASSWORD = var.dbpassword
    }
  }
}

resource "google_sql_database" "abc" {
  name      = "abc"
  instance  = google_sql_database_instance.master.name
  charset   = "UTF8"
  collation = "en_US.UTF8"

  provisioner "local-exec" {
    command = "psql -h ${google_sql_database_instance.master.public_ip_address} -p 5432 -U postgres -d abc -f \"/tmp/abc-postgres.sql\""
    environment = {
      PGPASSWORD = var.dbpassword
    }
  }
}

resource "google_sql_database" "jkl" {
  name      = "jkl"
  instance  = google_sql_database_instance.master.name
  charset   = "UTF8"
  collation = "en_US.UTF8"
}

output "database_public_ip_address" {
  value = google_sql_database_instance.master.public_ip_address
}
```

Comment: Can you share the terraform configuration that deletes the pg db?

Comment: Sure. Edited into the question now.

Answer (score 1):

I would use [graph](https://www.terraform.io/docs/commands/graph.html) to see the visual representation of execution plan.

`terraform graph -type=plan-destroy`

The output will be in DOT format and you can use [GraphViz](http://www.graphviz.org/) to generate charts and convert to an image by making use of `dot`:

`terraform graph -type=plan-destroy | dot -Tsvg > graph.svg`

After knowing that is the problem I would add  a [dependencies](https://learn.hashicorp.com/terraform/getting-started/dependencies.html) to your resource.

```
# New resource for the S3 bucket our application will use.
resource "aws_s3_bucket" "example" {
  # NOTE: S3 bucket names must be unique across _all_ AWS accounts, so
  # this name must be changed before applying this example to avoid naming
  # conflicts.
  bucket = "terraform-getting-started-guide"
  acl    = "private"
}

# Change the aws_instance we declared earlier to now include "depends_on"
resource "aws_instance" "example" {
  ami           = "ami-2757f631"
  instance_type = "t2.micro"

  # Tells Terraform that this EC2 instance must be created only after the
  # S3 bucket has been created.
  depends_on = [aws_s3_bucket.example]
}
```

Comment: I tried the graph. Couldn't make sense of the graphic it produced, it was too scrunched up. But I think I do know what the underlying issue is (the pod does not shut down soon enough even though TF says it has done). There's already a dependency preventing the pods being created before the database.